# How to return all the forms of a word in the English language with C#?

Tags: c#, nlp

Is there a way to find all the forms of a word in C#. I need to write a program where the user inputs a word such as `box` and the program returns the a string array of all the forms of the word like below.

`box unboxed boxing` 
and when a user enters a word like `battery` the program may output as below

`battery batteries`.
Is there an existing implementation of this or how can I proceed to accomplish that?
Thank You for your help.

Comment: There is no way to do this using just C#. You would need to define/ find a list with all the existing words and their forms. You'd have to query that list to find what you are looking for

Comment: @rbdeenk, Do you have access to such a list?

Comment: Sadly I don't, and I don't think it would be very easy to find one

Comment: Okay will try to build some kind of text file

Comment: oke i found two, i think might suite you https://www.bestwordlist.com/allwords.htm, https://en.wikwik.org/allwords.htm the thing is you'd still have to either write an algorithm to determine which word forms belong to which word and then it has to place them in the right form. Or you have to do that by hand

Comment: You saved me rbdeenk, God bless you

Comment: Yeah or I will search half the length of the word I need if the length is 5 and above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244879/discussion-between-rbdeenk-and-techgeek).